# Find oldest post — WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Thanks to some answers on here, I've managed to distinguish my posts into the *latest* post and all the rest. However, it needs to be the *oldest* post. Here is my current `loop`:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php $post = $posts[0]; $c=0;?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<!-- first post -->
<?php $c++;
if( $c == 1) :?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner_box">
        <ul>
            <div class="title">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
            </div>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        </a>
        </ul>
        <div class="down">a</div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php else :?>
    <!-- second post -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner_box">
        <ul>
            <div class="title">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
            </div>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        </a>
        </ul>
        <div class="up">b</div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>`
```

I saw somewhere that you can use a while loop to target the last post from a post.length. However, I am unsure how to implement this.

Comment: Do you need to style ONLY the oldest post or the oldest post and the posts just before it? In essence, if there are only 10 posts (10 being ID of the oldest), do you want to retrieve 10{special styling} then 9,8,7,etc{normal styling} or do you ONLY want 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're right. Use [`count`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php).

Suppose the total posts is 5 for `$total_posts = count($posts);`.
You'll have to check your `$counter` for `total - 1` as the array is `$posts[0], $posts[1], $posts[2], $posts[3], $posts[4]`.

```
<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) : 
    $counter = 0;
    $total_posts = count($posts) - 1; 

    while ( have_posts() ) : 
        the_post(); 
        if( $counter == $total_posts ) {
            ?>
            <div class="container"><?php // CUSTOM CODE FOR LAST ARTICLE ?></div>
            <?php
        } else {
            ?>
            <div class="container"><?php // CUSTOM CODE FOR THE REST OF ARTICLES ?></div>
            <?php
        }
        $counter++;
    endwhile;   
endif;
```

Note that you only need to open `<?php` and close `?>` when changing from PHP to HTML, using them at every line is very confusing.

Comment: Thanks. Where would I put my content if I were to use this method? (`<div class="container">` etc.)

Comment: Updated the answer with the basics, just adapt it to match your original code.